# Transfer string data from ASP classic to ASP.NET popup page

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I have a classic asp page from which I open a popup page in ASP.NET. How would I send data from classic ASP to ASP.Net popup without using query strings?

Comment: I really don't see the point :) If it is because you want to hide the data transfered you need to write it into a dabase or such. Using POST can do the trick, but it will NOT be invisible! The data will be stored in the browser and will be easily seen via fx Mozilla Firebug or such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You submit a POST to the new page containing the hidden values.

More specifically,

Have the values needed placed into a form on the old page. Then cause the form to submit as a POST targeting the new page.

Your new page will receives the Form variables and process them accordingly.